# How to log the app server IPs or localhost ports, to which nginx proxies/load balances the incoming requests to?

Tags: node.js, express, docker, nginx, pm2

**What am I trying to do?**

I am running a minimal [express generated](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) app on 3 ports (`3000`, `3001` and `3002`) on the `localhost`. And using `nginx` (listening on port `80`) to load balance the incoming requests.

I am trying the log the ports (one of `3000`, `3001` and `3002`) to which `nginx` forwarded the requests to.

**What am I doing currently?**

1. I open 3 terminal windows
2. Navigate to the app's directory and run `PORT=300X npm start`, where X is `0`, `1` and `2`.
3. In a 4th terminal run `ab -c 10 -n 2000 http://localhost/`

The results look something similar to the following:

[image]

I can see the results almost evenly distributed to the 3 ports.

**Now, what am I stuck with?**

The recommended method to deploy Node.js applications in production is via using a process manager, such as, [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/), which would run my app as daemons.

I run `PORT=3000 pm2 start bin/www -f` 3 times, changing the `PORT` value each time.

`pm2` output:

[image: pm2 output]

The `access_log` format in the nginx conf file is:

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                     '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                     '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" $server_port';
```

The log file has entries of the format:

```
::1 - - [20/Mar/2018:12:15:39 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 134 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162 Safari/537.36" "-" 80
```

with no information about the actual `port` the request was forwarded to. It only logs the port which `nginx` is listening to. How do I log these out? In my example, these are `localhost` ports. In production, these can be private IP addresses of the app servers.

I have linked the `nginx` conf files for reference:

1. [nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/bensooraj/5cc1825bd4c6db0b5d2a176d5b060c16) residing at `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
2. [default.conf](https://gist.github.com/bensooraj/57001869f8adc3ed622f14b7c3ef4cb6) residing at `/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf` sym linked at `/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf`

I am running on macOS Sierra (v10.12.6).

Please, let me know if something is unclear with my explanation. I will elaborate.

Comment: did u try pm2 logs

Comment: Awesome! `pm2 logs` do give me 3 logs (one for each port). So, going by that, if I have one nginx server acting as a proxy for multiple app servers, I will have to collate/consolidate pm2 logs from each app server and then process them, right? Does `nginx` have a native way of accomplishing this, so I have the consolidated logs all in one place? Thanks again!

Comment: pm2 log will give all the logs if process is started with in same process.yml file. Try to put all processes in process.yml so by doing pm2 logs will give you all logs.

Comment: or you can try keymatics which will give logs on browser key matrics is free for two instances